# Is the a way to share a preconfigured vscode.dev?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The situation is, I want to share my settings of vscode.dev to others. That could include

- extensions installed
- tabs opened (not files, but some extension related tabs such as panels or previews)

So the person who clicked on the shared link can go to vscode.dev, but with my configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Settings Sync`, its the easiest way: [Settings Sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync)

You could try to create a `settings.json` too, and share that file with others.

Comment: `Settings Sync` will save settings in your account. That means if anyone else opens the editor it won't have settings synced. (Unless you give your account credentials, I don't think it's what @River wants).

Comment: To complement: The best way to do this is to use the Settings Sync extension. This extension allows you to sync your settings, extensions, and other data across multiple machines. It also allows you to share your settings with others. To do this, you will need to create a GitHub account and then link it to the Settings Sync extension. Once you have done this, you can then share your settings with others by providing them with a link to your GitHub repository.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here.  The `Settings Sync` linked to in the answer is not an extension.  And that link says nothing about sharing the sync with others, because `Profiles` are the way to do that.  There is an extension called `Settings Sync` that pre-dated the built-in Settings Sync functionality and Profiles.  That extension has 250 open issues and hasn't been updated in over 3 years.    If someone can demonstrate how to share the built-in settings, etc. using the built-in Settings Sync that would be interesting...

Answer (score 0):

I think the only solutions you have here is to use either [GitHub Codespaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/codespaces) ([Dev Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/containers)) or store config in repository.

Basically you will not have a link for preconfigured vscode.dev. The idea is to have all required configuration in `devcontainer.json` file committed it to repository. So whenever the repository is opened VSCode uses the file to configure environment.

Also you can change you settings in Workspace and right click on extensions and click "add to workspace recommendations". That will create   `.vscode/extensions.json`, `.vscode/settings.json` and commit `.vscode` folder into repository.

TLDR: commit VSCode configuration files into repository and open repository in vscode.dev

Answer (score 0):

Look into Profiles, which can be enabled in your Settings (currently `experimental` but will be made generally available in vscode v1.75 due out very soon.

Current setting in Stable: `Workbench > Experimental > Settings Profiles: Enabled`

There is no setting for Profiles in the Insiders Build, it is just enabled by default.  I assume when v1.75 Stable comes out that will also be the case.

See [v1.75 Release Notes: Profiles](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_75.md#profiles):

> We are happy to announce that the Profiles feature is now generally
> available in VS Code. A Profile can include extensions, settings,
> keyboard shortcuts, UI state, tasks, and user snippets. You can
> customize VS Code for different development scenarios like data
> science, documentation writing or for multiple programming languages
> like Python or Java. If you have different VS Code setups based on
> workflow like Work or Demo, you could also save those as different
> profiles. You can open multiple workspaces (folders) with different
> profiles applied simultaneously.

{image omitted]

> You can also export and import profiles to share them with your
> colleagues, friends or students to help them get started with VS Code.
>
> The following video demonstrates how to export a profile using a
> GitHub gist in order to share it with someone. Users that receive the
> profile link can preview the shared profile in VS Code for the Web and
> import it to their local VS Code instance.

There is a nice mp4 demonstration in the link, but it appears SO would take that format.

You can export a Profile to a Github Gist so that it can be imported by someone else or to a local file you can share (or yourself to a new maching, etc.) - my demo shows all the settings, UI State and extensions it can include.

More info on Profiles at [v1.69 Release Notes: Settings Profiles](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_69.md#settings-profiles)

[image: demo of Profile creation and sharing]

Comment: Even though this is not as simple as I thought it could be, it is the closest to what I was looking for.
Thanks.
I will keep this question open and see if we get better solutions in the future.