# VSCode for multi user

Tags: visual-studio-code

We have a laptop shared by 2 people.  Both using VSCode in the same Windows user sign-in account.  Is it possible to set different user profiles for the 2 person ?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try the `--user-data-dir <dir>` option when starting `code`? You can also try to use Visual Studio Code in portable mode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable.
Anyway, two users that share the same windows account is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @Jepessen Thanks very much for --user-data-dir <dir>.  I think this would work.

Comment: Profiles might work, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75301874/836330

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have 2 GitHub accounts. How can I use both when I am working in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625513/i-have-2-github-accounts-how-can-i-use-both-when-i-am-working-in-vs-code)